# Como eu faço para aparecer os comandos de dentro da minha função em Javascript na tela da minha pagina HTML ao clicar em um botão?

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Quero sortear 6 números diferentes de 1 a 60 e desejo mostrar esses números na minha tela html. Fiz o código em Javascript, mas estou com dificuldades em fazer com que esses 6 números apareçam na minha tela quando eu clico no botão, tentei usar o inner.HTML mas fiquei com dúvidas em como colocá-lo no meu código.

Segue meu código abaixo

1. Este é meu código usando html e Javascript

---

```
<main>
    <h1>Loteria</h1>
    <div class="box">
        <button id="btnSortear" onclick="sortearIntervalo()">Sortear</button>
    </div>
    <span id="output"></span>
<script>
    function sortearIntervalo(min,max) {
      min = Math.floor(1);
      max = Math.floor(60);
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min)+ min);
    }

    var listaSorteados = [];
    while(listaSorteados.length <6) {
    var numSorteado = sortearIntervalo();
    if(listaSorteados.indexOf(numSorteado)=== -1) {
        listaSorteados[listaSorteados.length] = numSorteado;
    }       
    console.log(listaSorteados);
</script>
</main>
```

Comment: Já viu `document.getElementById` para buscar no dom o elemento e mostrar nele ? (existem outros também, mas, esse é o mais simples)

Comment: como disse o @novic tente usar `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = numSorteado` por exemplo. Vai precisar exibir cada um, mas use isso como um começo para resolver o problema

Comment: Acho que criando uma nova função chamada botaoSortear() e usando o document.querySelector(#output).innerHTML = listaSorteados, funciona. Vou analisar com mais calma, ainda assim, obrigada pelas dicas!

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas inconsistências no teu código, nomeadamente porque a função `sortearIntervalo` recebe parâmetro mas depois não são passados quando a invocas no evento `onClick`.

Para conseguires introduzir o resultado do sorteio na DOM podes usar `innerHTML` (não `inner.HTML`).

Fiz algumas alterações ao código que forneceste e desta forma deve funcionar. Adicionei ainda a quantidade de números a gerar como argumento da função.

```js
function sortearIntervalo(quantidade, min, max) {
  if (max < min || max - min < quantidade) return;
  
  const intervalo = [...Array(max - min + 1).keys()].map((item) => item + min);
  const numerosSorteados = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < quantidade; i ++) {
    const indiceAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * intervalo.length);
    const numeroSorteado = intervalo.splice(indiceAleatorio, 1)[0];
    
    numerosSorteados.push(numeroSorteado);
  }
  
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = numerosSorteados.join(', ');
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Loteria</h1>
  <div class="box">
    <button id="btnSortear" onclick="sortearIntervalo(6, 1, 100)">Sortear</button>
  </div>
  <span id="output"></span>
</main>
```

Comment: Olá, muito obrigada pela ajuda! Comecei a estudar Javascript muito recente e ainda estou pegando o jeito. Vou dar uma olhadinha com mais calma no seu código, mas já vi que vai me auxiliar bastante.